# Multiple Key Inputs Fail After 4 Keys Held

Tags: javascript, input, keyboard-events

Sort of new to programming, made a test demo to figure out how key inputs worked. The demo looked good until I started noticing that some keys were not being registered. I just pressed and held q -> w -> e -> r -> t and the t did not show up in the output unless I released the other keys. Here is my code, it is pretty basic.

```js
var p1 = document.getElementById("p1");
var keys = [];

document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  keys[e.keyCode] = true;
  update();
});

document.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
  keys[e.keyCode] = false;
  update();
});

function update() {
  console.log(keys);

  p1.innerText = "";

  for (i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) { //checks the entire array and outputs the arr position, which is the keycode, if true
    if (keys[i]) {
      p1.innerText += i + " | ";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<p id="p1">testing</p>
```

Any ideas on why the 5th input sometimes doesn't map? Are there ways to get around this?

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with keyboard input from a programming side in general, but I think usually pressing more than 4 keys at once doesn't work in any program, which has me guessing that it's a hardware "issue" (if you call it that. It might be more like a feature).

Comment: Bare in mind, most keyboards have a concurrent-key limit, so it may not be your code causing the issue.

Comment: Well if I use specific keys I can go up to seven, but it seems random. The combination qweryipn all maps correctly, but letters such as t, u, o, v, c, and x refuse to join the group.

Comment: Note, that when you **press'n'hold** the keyboard button, it will fire `keydown` event a lot of times per secont until you will release it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is hardware-specific and depends on the ["rollover"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rollover_(key)) limitations imposed by your OS, keyboard, and possibly the software (browser) in question. For example, on my system, your code correctly triggers for q+w+e+r+t+y, but not a seventh key. So, it appears your max is 4, while mine is 6.

To answer your specific questions:

> Any ideas on why the 5th input sometimes doesn't map?

In short, because something—probably the keyboard itself, but possibly other hardware in your computer or software—is disregarding the additional keys.

> Are there ways to get around this?

Not reliably, in the sense that it may work for some users, but you can't deploy code like this on the web and expect it to work for all users. Some older hardware may support only 2 keys at once.

Comment: I made a [**Codepen demo**](https://codepen.io/edcottrell/pen/oOwrYK) of how this works, which you can use to test in different configurations.

Comment: I am also using codepen. And to restate my comment above, if I use specific keys I can go up to seven, but it seems random. The combination qweryipn all maps correctly, but letters such as t, u, o, v, c, and x refuse to join the group.

Comment: @ARCS2016 That's really interesting. Nonetheless, you're running into limitations of your hardware, which may then be further restricted (*i.e.*, some keys may be ignored) by your OS or other software. Just out of curiosity, is there a reason you need this kind of high concurrency? Or are you just testing what works?

Comment: @ARCS2016 I suppose, Ed Cottrell is right. Event using desktop applications with keyboard-driven functionality, some keys are available to press together (up to 7), and some keys are not.

Comment: Have you seen those browser games that allow two people to control two characters on one keyboard? (Such as Fireboy and Watergirl, Matrix Bullet Time, and Tank Trouble) I am attempting to make a game with that feature, and I can't have keys just not activating, as this game will be PVP.

Comment: @ARCS2016 Got it. In that case, you'll probably want to design some fallbacks into your system to degrade gracefully. That is, if someone's keyboard doesn't quite support what they need, give them some sort of workaround. It sounds like a fun challenge to implement something like this over the web, with all of the weirdness of coding for (lots of) different browsers, but it will definitely be a challenge. Have fun!